# Laravel failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel

> fopen(C:\lighttpd\htdocs\storage\app\upload/LqlmfPRYJovsfn6Snm5qF0GCQf2QBrdfhHmkiUWO.): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Когда загружаю изображение все нормально, а вот exe файл не пускает..

```
  <form action="{{ route('offers.add') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
     <input type="file" id="file" name="file" >
    </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

думаю стоит обратить внимание на прямые и обратные слеши, привести все к одному виду и использовать встроенную константу `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` если этот путь собирается руками, ну и удостовериться что вот эта папка существует `C:\lighttpd\htdocs\storage\app\upload`

Comment: я тоже подумал на слеш, но где изменить? папка существует

Comment: ну по коду смотреть нужно, как ты файл переносишь из временной папки? `Request::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $name);` типа такого? Нужно тогда смотреть в `$destinationPath`

Comment: $file->store('upload');

Comment: тогда он там видимо атоматом добавляется, попробуй какой-нибудь другой способ сохранения на диске файла, который позволяет указать месторасположение

Comment: storeAs работает